# Runtime Error when sending a search request to outlook for a keyword that does not exist in the mailbox

Tags: odata, office365, outlook-api

When searching for a keyword ("Test email"), using Outlook API, and the keyword exist in my mailbox, I retrived a result within a second. However, if the keyword ("blablabla") does not exist in the mailbox I do not get a reply. Almost after 2 minutes I get a runtime error.

```
http get on: https://outlook.office365.com:443/api/v2.0/users/user@sub.onmicrosoft.com/messages?$search=blablablablabla&$top=100&$select=Sender,ToRecipients,CcRecipients,Weblink,Subject,ReceivedDateTime,BodyPreview

http headers:
Authorization: bearer theToken
x-AnchorMailbox: theEmailAddress
```

I expected to get an HTTP Response that says something like "Could not find any result"

Instead I get no reply upto two minutes and than a runtime error with that yellow background that instructs to turn on

```xml
<customError mode="Off" />
```

Though the http staus code is 200.

I think as an API consumer I should not get such replies.